# Why is my qbittorrent search plugin not supported?

Tags: python, plugins, bittorrent, torrent

I started to write a search plugin for qBitTorrent, to search through a torrent website.

I followed the instructions given in qbittorrent's wiki : https://github.com/qbittorrent/search-plugins/wiki/How-to-write-a-search-plugin

When I try to install it however, I get the error:

```
Couldn't install "zetorrents" search engine plugin. Plugin is not supported.
```

I already have a couple of search plugins that are working just fine

I went through these dated threads

- https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/11149
- https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/13122

and tried their solutions anyway ( clearing the qbittorrent nova3's cache mostly ) but had no luck

I believe my code is the issue but I cannot fathom why.

I come here to ask for help finishing this small project available on Github at
https://github.com/alexandre-eliot/zetorrents_qbittorrent_search_plugin

I also tried testing my search plugin [as in the wiki](https://github.com/qbittorrent/search-plugins/wiki/How-to-write-a-search-plugin#testing-your-plugin) but did not get an output

If anyone has any clue on the reason of the matter, I would be very pleased to hear your comments

Answer (score 1):

Let this be a lesson for all developers and myself included.
Let this be a reminder that we should all seek humility upon our work and pride upon our failures.

The issue was simple, yet it seemed transparent for my eyes.

My class was named `zeTorrents` and the name of the file that hold it, is `zetorrents.py`.

The culprit of my headache was simple yet fearless : a capital letter.

As often it is when programming, the name of the file and the class that it holds should be named identically.

I had to change `zeTorrents` to `zetorrents` for qBitTorrent to accept my plugin